# Measuring SNR on a mulltiplexed coax power and data cable

Tags: noise, signal, oscilloscope, snr

Please excuse the basic knowledge I have in this field.

Within my workplace, we constantly use long 300m-6km coax cable which carries HV (Up to 400VDC) and DSL data.

We have encountered problems whereby using a cable length too long has resulted in interrupted data, as well RF pickup in some instances that interrupt data.

I would like to be able to carry out physical tests on cables not only for my own sanity so I can see exactly what is happening and when, but also to aid in isolation of where problems are occurring and to be able to send visuals back to the office demonstrating where our problems arise.

I have been looking at different options, ie, tablet based oscilloscope (Handy as it makes the unit easier to carry/use in the workplace), PC based oscilloscope (Pico), etc. I'm not sure on the best route to take here.

Could some recommend not only an ideal test tool, but a method for measuring Signal strength, SNR and RF pickup (This tends to happen when we operate motors in close proximity).

As I say, my knowledge in this field is extremely limited, but as well as just being able to carry out the test, I  am hoping to learn an understanding of what is happening etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at RF network analyzers.

Comment: Are you saying the data is sent, using DSL protocol, on the HVDC coaxial center conductor? Or over a more conventional telephone style cable that runs along with the HVDC coax? Can you energize/ deenergize the HVDC during your testing?

Comment: This is a complicated problem, as I completed a project exactly like this (DSL + power over coax, few km) some time ago. You are on the right track, however, just looking at the SNR & RF in the field is a good step but not enough: it will explain the data rate. But analyzing the drop outs requires much more.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt, yes, the data is sent via DSL protocol along with HVDC on the centre conductor. I can power down the cable for testing, but powering down will also stop the data transmission.

Comment: Thank you for your input @P2000. Could you explain what more I would need to look at? I have spoken to a manufacturer of one of the pieces of equipment and they explained how the transmitter scans the cable characteristics and adjusts it's protocol accordingly. I do feel I will have to try and look at this in more depth too.

Comment: It's a long explanation that I will not type up, but we can get in touch off this site if you wish. See bottom of my profile. I'll be more than happy to have a chat.

Comment: Thank you @P2000, that's an interesting read. Feel free to drop me a message. Kirk Gooch.